# pypylon : Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Script used:

```
from pypylon import pylon

cam = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice())
cam.Open()
print(cam.GetDeviceInfo)
cam.Close()
[enter image description here][1]
print("done")
```

OS: Windows 10 64 bit

Camera: Basler acA640

Connected via USB 3.0

Error while running the above script:

> Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E)

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? Or isn't there any?

Comment: C:\Users\Dell\python.exe C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\open_cv\pylon_import_sample.py
Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E)